# How to import function from iputils.dll library?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using the iputils.dll for getting the IP address.
When I'm using it with InnoSetup 5.3.9 (ANSI) it works fine, but when I use the same function import in InnoSetup 5.4.2 (Unicode) it throws the following error:

```
cannot import dll :: path\iputils.dll
```

Here's the function import:

```
[code]
function GetLocalIPAddress: PAnsiChar;
  external 'GetLocalIPAddress@files:IPUtils.dll stdcall';
```

Where might be the problem ?

Comment: What is the `GetLocalIPAddress` function prototype ? You have absolutely no activity here except posting questions. Don't hesitate to [write comments, vote for answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and be active here. Feedback is very important part of this Q&A site. Take a look for instance, [how to accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541).

Comment: Sorry, but `no response=no answer` from my side... Anyway, I know that `IPUtils` library is just another of those suspicious, undocumented, black boxed russian InnoSetup libraries, so you might not be even sure with that prototype. However, [sharing of this library](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=4801&start=768&limit=1&m=1) in a base 64 encoded zip file posted as plain text made me laugh (registration that might help with that doesn't seem to work for me anyhow).

Comment: It must certainly contain some supersecret code :-) Now thinking about it in a serious way, using installer extensions would be a nice way to share viruses. Installer usually asks for elevation and can do almost everything with your system, btw...

Comment: To your activity, you know it's [not the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931576/inno-setup-how-to-detect-dvd-drive-letter-automatically#comment17563590_12931576). I might give you the solution there, here maybe too. Instead I'm voting to close this Q as too localized... Howgh! :-)